# filter objects with same ids from two separate arrays of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering, arrayobject

Array One:

```
Cuisines in Profile      =======>>  [{"id": 2, "name": "Indian"}, {"id": 4, "name": "Mexican"}, {"id": 5, "name": "Mediterranean"}, {"id": 6, "name": "Middle Eastern"}, {"id": 7, "name": "Chinese"}, {"id": 8, "name": "Japanese"}, {"id": 9, "name": "Italian"}, {"id": 10, "name": "Pick for Me"}, {"id": 16, "name": "BBQ"}]
```

Array Two:

```
Selected Cuisines        =======>>  [{"cuisine_id": 6, "id": 1260}, {"cuisine_id": 16, "id": 1262}, {"cuisine_id": 8, "id": 1268}, {"cuisine_id": 10, "id": 1269}]
```

Now I want to get a new filtered objects from Array one where id from Array one and cuisine_id from Array two are the same

Expected Output:

```
[{"id": 6, "name": "Middle Eastern"}, {"id": 8, "name": "Japanese"}, {"id": 10, "name": "Pick for Me"}, {"id": 16, "name": "BBQ"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const cuisines = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Indian' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Mexican' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Mediterranean' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Middle Eastern' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Chinese' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Japanese' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Italian' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Pick for Me' },
  { id: 16, name: 'BBQ' },
];
const selected = [
  { cuisine_id: 6, id: 1260 },
  { cuisine_id: 16, id: 1262 },
  { cuisine_id: 8, id: 1268 },
  { cuisine_id: 10, id: 1269 },
];
const result = cuisines.filter(c => selected.some(s => s.cuisine_id === c.id));
console.log(result);
```

An alternate way to achieve the same result would be to use a `for` loop.

```js
const cuisines = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Indian' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Mexican' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Mediterranean' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Middle Eastern' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Chinese' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Japanese' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Italian' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Pick for Me' },
  { id: 16, name: 'BBQ' },
];

const selected = [
  { cuisine_id: 6, id: 1260 },
  { cuisine_id: 16, id: 1262 },
  { cuisine_id: 8, id: 1268 },
  { cuisine_id: 10, id: 1269 },
];

const result = [];

for (const cuisine of cuisines) {
  for (const s of selected) {
    if (s.cuisine_id === cuisine.id) {
      result.push(cuisine);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

In terms of performance, the `filter` and `some` method approach is likely to be faster than the `for` loop, especially for large arrays. This is because the `filter` and `some` methods are optimised for performance and can take advantage of multiple CPU cores, whereas the for loop approach is limited to a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Using filter() and find() functions-**

From the `cuisines` array filter those items which get found in the `selected` array.

Here is the demo-

```js
const cuisines = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Indian' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Mexican' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Mediterranean' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Middle Eastern' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Chinese' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Japanese' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Italian' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Pick for Me' },
  { id: 16, name: 'BBQ' },
];
const selected = [
  { cuisine_id: 6, id: 1260 },
  { cuisine_id: 16, id: 1262 },
  { cuisine_id: 8, id: 1268 },
  { cuisine_id: 10, id: 1269 },
];
const result = cuisines.filter(c => selected.find(s => s.cuisine_id == c.id))
console.log(result);
```

**Method 2: Using filter(), map() and includes() functions-**

Apply `map()` on the `selected` array to get only `cuisine_id` in the array and then use `includes` to check if this mapped array includes the requested cuisine id.

Here is the demo-

```js
const cuisines = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Indian' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Mexican' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Mediterranean' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Middle Eastern' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Chinese' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Japanese' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Italian' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Pick for Me' },
  { id: 16, name: 'BBQ' },
];
const selected = [
  { cuisine_id: 6, id: 1260 },
  { cuisine_id: 16, id: 1262 },
  { cuisine_id: 8, id: 1268 },
  { cuisine_id: 10, id: 1269 },
];
const result = cuisines.filter(c => selected.map(s => s.cuisine_id).includes(c.id))
console.log(result);
```